Convert Image under UV Light to RGB?
I have an Image (banknotes) as a dataset that is under UV Light. I want to image process it back to RGB again in order to detect which banknote is it (if it is 20, 50, 100 and so on bill)
Since this project will be used in a hardware I dont want to turn on and off the UV lights to attain its efficiency and speed.
I have created a code that will convert its contrast, warmth and tint.
def change_contrast(img, level):
    factor = (259 * (level + 255)) / (255 * (259 - level))
    def contrast(c):
        return 128 + factor * (c - 128)
    return img.point(contrast)

def adjust_warmth(image, warmth_factor):
    b, g, r = cv2.split(image)
    
    r = cv2.add(r, int(warmth_factor))  # Increase red channel
    b = cv2.subtract(b, int(warmth_factor))  # Decrease blue channel

    warmed_image = cv2.merge([b, g, r])
    return np.clip(warmed_image, 0, 255).astype(np.uint8)

def adjust_tint(image, tint_factor):
    tinted_image = np.zeros_like(image)
    
    # Increase or decrease each channel
    tinted_image[:, :, 0] = cv2.add(image[:, :, 0], int(tint_factor))  # Blue channel
    tinted_image[:, :, 1] = cv2.add(image[:, :, 1], int(tint_factor))  # Green channel
    tinted_image[:, :, 2] = cv2.add(image[:, :, 2], int(tint_factor))  # Red channel
    
    return np.clip(tinted_image, 0, 255).astype(np.uint8)

This are the sample I've made. But its not enough to attain the original color of it.


new_image = change_contrast(Image.open('20-f.jpg'), 50)
new_image = new_image.rotate(90)

new_image_np = np.array(new_image)
img3_warmth = adjust_warmth(new_image_np, -25)
img3_tint = adjust_tint(img3_warmth, -35)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,12))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.imshow(img3_tint)
plt.show()

This is the image i want to attain.


After converting it back to its original color, how do you plan to detect which banknote it is?

If your goal is to detect the number through OCR for example, why do you need it in RGB format? What would that bring you?

Typically, you would convert to grayscale, improve contrast and do the detection without colours.

I think all of this is liable to accept counterfeit money. I see no discussion of detecting the security features built into banknotes.

@ken I would like to color detect it as the first phase of my detection in order to lower the size of the images I would use in order to authenticate it using SURF features matching

What is "color detect"? Why is it needed for SURF? Anyway, what you really need is not to restore the original colors, but to convert them to "color detect" compatible colors. I think you could just try white balancing, like this.

Converting UV to RGB is physically impossible.
UV is invisible to the human eye. It's also invisible to most cameras, which have a filter for visible light (or R,G,B spectra anyway) so their images look like something we're used to.
We "see" it because some materials absorb UV and re-emit it as other wavelengths, which we can see.
You illuminated your banknote with UV-spectrum light. You have only obtained information on what the material emits when excited by UV. You have gained no information on what parts of the visible light spectrum the material would reflect.
There is no way to infer an object's appearance under lighting with some spectrum, if you only have images of the object illuminated under other spectra.

That's the best answer you can expect, given the question and constraints.
If you wanted to merely tell the value of the banknote, you can do that under UV light just fine.

If the UV light was pure, I'm sure you'd be right.  But based on the sample presented here there might be enough bits of spectrum to get something usable.

no, there wouldn't. usual UV sources emit a narrow peak. the UV might scratch a bit of indigo, but it doesn't span anything longer than that (blue, green, yellow, red). humans can't see UV. we "see" UV because some substances absorb UV and re-emit that energy in other wavelengths. the distribution of this emission spectrum from UV excitation is going to be somewhat different from the reflection spectrum of the material. in particular, you don't see the note appearing white, but you do see those little scattered strips which aren't visible under normal light. we could take this to [physics.se]
